# C++ Developing a Scrolling Audio Timeline

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, qtmultimedia

I am developing a QT multimedia audio application that needs to have an audio monitor feature.   The application currently has regular callback (Signals/Slots) with PCM data samples (44.1khz, Stereo). In order to display microphone activity, I take every 100th slot callback and display it but that is not very useful as it is just a snapshot of one audio packet.

I need to display a live audio timeline similar to the ones seen on audio recorder tools like audacity or I would prefer a display timeline like that in a WhatsApp audio message with highs and lows following audio speech energy.

My plotting code uses [QCustomPlot](https://www.qcustomplot.com/) where it displays 1000 PCM16 audio samples where each Y value represents the audio value and X represents the time.  I am thinking I need to do something along the following lines:

This previous X axis represented 1000 * (1/44100) (i.e. 4.1ms) of audio.

If instead I wish to have a 5 second horizontal scrolling window represented in this same 1000 point plot, then the entire window would correspond to 44100 * 5 (i.e. 220,500) PCM samples.

In order to display something meaningful in this window (for example an RMS calculation on the audio (see [here](https://www.embedded.com/improve-your-root-mean-calculations/)), I am thinking that I would need to maintain a 1024 rms sample ring buffer to contain the updated audio signal.  I would push in a new result once I have an rms result (220,500/1000) and discard the oldest or something along those lines.

Comment: I have developed an application like that, and it has been quite successful.  Does your question have... like... a question part of the question?

Comment: Audacity is open source. You could consult how that project approaches the problem https://github.com/audacity/audacity

Comment: @Eljay Would you be able to share the application you developed - is it open source?  If not, could you comment on the algorithm which I outlined which would be my approach to developing such a widget.

Comment: @fdcpp I looked at audacity - but its very complicated to find out where exactly it displays the timeline details- I spent more than 30 mins yesteday looking for where it calculated a running RMS calculation but I could not find it - let alone the timeline display code.  Audacity creates an RMS like timeline along with the audio peaks and mins in an overly complicated timeline.

Comment: If you had a deep grasp of UI, the graphics pipeline and class heirarchy of audacity then I think 30 minutes may be sufficient. A more realistic timescale will likely be a few days if not a week. If that is too long, I recommend taking a fast graphics prototyping approach. Maybe use processing.org or P5.js to rough-out the idea first. Then you can present a more self-contained question.

Comment: @fdcpp I have a fine understanding of the UI (I have a working Qt UI with oscilloscope like functionality working just fine), I don't require a beginnners coding course to recompose the question (even if it was a bit vague), I was looking for high level guidance on the algorithm approach to develop a sliding RMS like activity monitor similar to how WhatsApp recording or audacity recording (overly complex as I do not need both peak & rms activity superimposed upon eachother) works.

Comment: Each point on your graph will represent an amount of time between it and the next. Find that duration in samples as that is your window. It doesn’t need to be accurate unless you intend on having a labeled magnitude / dB y-axis. For RMS you work backwards so square the values,  add them all, divide by the number then take the square root. Squaring is actually just a means of removing the sign, so you could simply `abs` your values for a quicker operation. Mean values are pretty straight forward and you don’t need to `sqrt` something that hasn’t been squared. It isn’t accurate

Comment: If you want something like WhatsApp that is just peak finding in a window, which (if you don’t need accuracy) is probably the better approach.

Comment: For rms, you would need an overlapping window, for peaks you don’t